# Login Popup in AngularJS with SpringSecurity

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring, spring-security

I have implemented spring security with my AngularJS page using Rest API. But, the problem is whenever I try to login using rest api from my custom login page, it asks me for the login and password in a popup like this:

[image]

Spring security configuration file:

```
@Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().exceptionHandling().and()
                .anonymous().and()
                .servletApi().and()
                .headers().cacheControl().and()
                .authorizeRequests()

                //allow anonymous resource requests
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/favicon.ico").permitAll()

                //allow anonymous POSTs to login
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,     "/webresources/login").permitAll()

                    .anyRequest().hasRole("USER").and()             

                    .addFilterBefore(new StatelessLoginFilter("/login", new TokenAuthenticationService("123abc"), new CustomJDBCDaoImpl() , authenticationManager()), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                    .addFilterBefore(new StatelessAuthenticationFilter(new TokenAuthenticationService("123abc")), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class).httpBasic();
    }
```

on Log In button click the controller will be:

```
app.controller('SigninFormController', ['$scope', '$http', '$state', function($scope, $http, $state) {
    $scope.user = {};
    $scope.authError = null;
    $scope.login = function() {
      $scope.authError = null;
      // Try to login
      $http.post('../api/verifyUser'+$scope.user.email+'&'+$scope.user.password, {},{
      headers : { "Authorization" : "BasicCustom" }
    })
      .then(function(response) {
          console.log(response);
        if ( !response.data.user ) {
          $scope.authError = 'Email or Password not right';
        }else{
          $state.go('home.go');
        }
      }, function(x) {
        $scope.authError = 'Server Error';
      });
    };
  }])
```

Any idea why I am getting this popup instead of home page?

Comment: Your header is wrong, { "Authorization" : "BasicCustom" }, should be {Authorization: Basic BASE64_USER:PASS}... and you are sending it to verifyUser and login is different url in your spring app.

Comment: But I am not using spring application login page. I want to use AngularJS login instead of spring security login. How can I fix this any idea?

Comment: I think that you are mixing the basic concept of authentication here. However it is quite hard to clarify this in one comment. I know it is quite long but try to read on this: https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/ more less from this section: "How Does it Work?" or "Create the Angular Application"

Comment: Just correct me if I am wrong, but you want to use BasicAuth, right?

Comment: No I want custom authentication using database

Comment: the BasicAuth is not about using database or not but about how you handle the login and password, and session (or actually a lack of it). and the popup you're getting is the BasicAuth pop up which comes up because you are using BasicAuth filter, from class HttpSecurity with this method: basicAuth()

Comment: So how can I avoid that?

Comment: You need to remove the Spring filters and write your own. Basically you can remove the two: addFilterBefore with all the spring classes inside.

Comment: @Atais you are right as in console I checked position 7 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'

Comment: @Atais you mean these two lines :.addFilterBefore(new StatelessLoginFilter("/login", new TokenAuthenticationService("123abc"), new CustomJDBCDaoImpl() , authenticationManager()), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                    .addFilterBefore(new StatelessAuthenticationFilter(new TokenAuthenticationService("123abc")), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class).httpBasic();

Comment: Do you have any example because I didn't get this point of writing my own?

Comment: well basically either read about what you are using or delete it. for now you are using basicauth (which in my opinion is ok, especially for angular) but maybe is not what you need. if you change your mind and need basic auth read on the spring tutorial i sent you before.

Comment: yes, if you dont want basic auth delete the two you mentioned. write your own means create your own authentication. no examples since you want your own :P so you are the king.

Answer (score 0):

that is because your basic authorization is failing,see the web console you might see problem with `OPTION` request

Comment: I didn't check it yet but if any then how can I resolve that?

Comment: just make sure you are passing correct authorization header and one thing i missed ,just check CORS are enabled on your server or not.this can happen due to CORS issues

Comment: Cors is enabled and I am using nginx to share the request and response

Comment: did you checked weather you have enabled access-control-allow-methods for allowing OPTION request  and access-control-allow-headers for allowing Authorization headers ?

Comment: No I didn't but how can I do that?

Comment: I have checked my configuration and there is nothing like CORS filter that I have defined externally. Second thing if  http
          .authorizeRequests()
              .anyRequest().authenticated();
 This code is for allowing authorization headers.. correct me if I am wrong. And still looking into the same issue

Comment: i don't much about spring , but on searching i got this @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://domain2.com", maxAge = 3600) ,this is something you should put on the controller to allow cross origin request